# Meteor insert uploaded into the console but not MongoDB

Tags: javascript, facebook, mongodb, meteor

I've configured a FB graph call that would retrieve data from the API, however I'm having trouble inserting it into MongoDb. Right now if I run `Photos.find().count();` in the browser it shows that there are photos, however if I run `db.Photos.find().count();` in MongoDb it shows nothing. Also, if I run `db.users.find();` in MongoDb it returns results from the FB user account, so MongoDb is talking to the API to some extent.

Any thoughts on what might be causing the issue?

Here is my code:

Client:

```
Template.test.events({
    'click #btn-user-data': function(e) {
        Meteor.call('getUserData', function(err, data) {
             if(err) console.error(err); 
         });
    }
});

Template.facebookphoto.helpers({
    pictures: function () {
        return Photos.find();
      }     
});
```

Server:

```
function Facebook(accessToken) {
    this.fb = Meteor.require('fbgraph');
    this.accessToken = accessToken;
    this.fb.setAccessToken(this.accessToken);
    this.options = {
        timeout: 3000,
        pool: {maxSockets: Infinity},
        headers: {connection: "keep-alive"}
    }
    this.fb.setOptions(this.options);
}

Facebook.prototype.query = function(query, method) {
    var self = this;
    var method = (typeof method === 'undefined') ? 'get' : method;
    var data = Meteor.sync(function(done) {
        self.fb[method](query, function(err, res) {
            done(null, res);
        });
    });
    return data.result;
}

Facebook.prototype.getUserData = function() {
    return this.query('me/photos');
}

Meteor.methods({
    getUserData: function() {
        var fb = new Facebook(Meteor.user().services.facebook.accessToken);
        var data = fb.getUserData();
        _.forEach(data.data, function(photo) {
            if(Photos.findOne({id: photo.id})) return;
            Photos.insert(photo, function(err) {
                    if(err) console.error(err); 
                });
            });
    }
});
```

Collection:

```
Photos = new Meteor.Collection('picture');
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show your initial `new Meteor.Collection` call?

Comment: Sure thing... just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `db.Photos.find().count();`, try `db.picture.find().count();`

`Photos` is just the name you gave to the JavaScript variable. The actual name of the collection in MongoDB is whatever you use when you initialized the `Collection` - in this case, `picture`.

Comment: Ahh, got it. That makes a lot more sense now. Thanks for the clarity.